# Django - URL template tag with 2 arguments

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm new to Django and sorry if the question is silly. I have a URL with two slugs, one for the category which is a manytomany field and one for the posts:

```
path('<slug:slug_staticpage>/<slug:slug>/', views.post, name='post_detail')
```

**views.py**

```
def post(request, slug, slug_staticpage):
    category = get_object_or_404(StaticPage, slug_staticpage=slug_staticpage)
    blogpost = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    page_id = category.pk
    related_posts = Post.objects.filter(static_page__pk=page_id)[:6]
    return render(request, "blog/blog-post-final.html", {'slug': slug, 'slug_staticpage': category.slug_staticpage, 'post':post, 'related_posts':related_posts})
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = RichTextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Published", default=now())
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Image", upload_to="blog", null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Author", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name="Categories", related_name="get_post")
    static_page = models.ManyToManyField(StaticPage, verbose_name="Página estática", related_name="get_post")
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
```

I want to display those URLs in my homepage via the template tag, but I don't know how to retrieve the slug_staticpage slug:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:post_detail'  slug_staticpage=post.slug_staticpage slug=post.slug %}">
```

The above syntax is not working, I can only retrieve the slug of the post.

Can someone help me sort this out? Thanks a lot for your precious help :)

Askew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by adding the following to models.py

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
   return reverse('blog:post_detail', kwargs={'slug_staticpage':self.static_page.slug_staticpage, 'slug':self.slug})
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As you have a Many-to-Many relationship, you should have a **single** url for *each* of those `static_page` objects.

You can achieve that via iterating over the `static_page` objects:

```
{% for slug_url in post.slug_staticpage.all %}
   <a href="{% url 'blog:post_detail'  slug_staticpage=slug_url slug=post.slug %}"> 
{% endfor %}
```

although I'm not sure whether you *really* need such relationship or not.

Comment: Does this help you fix the issue? if not, let me know about the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately it does not work, nothing happen and the link is not even appearing on the frontend. Basically what I'd like to achieve is that in the homepage I link to the latest 6 posts which have that URL path. But I cannot get the URL template tag right, everything else is working: I can correctly access posts and categories via the proper URL paths.

Comment: This is the error that I'm getting: Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug_staticpage': '', 'slug': 'test-post-slug'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug_staticpage>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$'] when I use my above mentioned URL template tag. So as said the slug of the post is working, but the slug related to the staticpage (which essentially is a category) is not and it's empty. I tried a lot of combinations that I could think of but no luck.

Comment: Does someone by any chance have a hint? I’m stuck with this for a long time now :( What I need to understand is how to pass the slug of a foreign key element’s (static_page) slug (slug_staticpage) in a url template tag for a blog post which has path /slug_staticpage/slug... {% url 'blog:post_detail'  slug_staticpage=post.static_page.slug_staticpage slug=post.slug %} slug=post.slug works fine but slug_staticpage... no clue how to pass that I’ve tried everything :( thanks in advance

Comment: @Askew The error message you mentioned in the last comment is complaining about `slug_staticpage`. It empty. Do you get any value when you add something like `<p>{{ slug_url }}</p>` in your template?

Comment: Hi Pedram, thanks for your precious help. Indeed it seems to be empty as I don't get any value back. But then views.py and urls.py work correctly and show the page if I search for it in the browser. Basically as far as I can see, the problem is retrieving that slug_staticpage variable